# An operator is positive definite if, and only if, it is non-negative and invertable

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, positive-definite

The question is the following:

**Show that an operator $T$ is positive-definite if, and only if, $T \geq 0$ and $T$ is invertable.**

My initial idea was to use the fact that an operator is positive-definite if, and only if, all its eigenvalues are positive, but I'm not sure how I could relate it to being invertable.

Also, does the $T \geq 0$ part come from the definition of a positive-definite operator that $\langle Tx, x \rangle > 0$, for $x \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$T \ge 0$ (positive semi-definite) implies the eigenvalues are nonnegative. Invertibility of $T$ means the eigenvalues are nonzero. Together, they imply the eigenvalues of $T$ are positive.

Comment: This is the $\Leftarrow$ proof, right? How would I prove that: $T$ is positive-definite $\Rightarrow$ $T \geq 0$ and invertable?

Comment: @2BDrB If the eigenvalues of $T$ are positive, then the eigenvalues are both nonnegative and nonzero.